# Excel Spreadsheet: Removing all data from cells in a square bracket

Tags: excel, substring, formula

I have the following data in an excel spreadsheet.

[image: Excel Spreadsheet of scores]

The first data entry in each cell is contained within square brackets and contains the student's first attempt at a test. The second percentage is their final score.

I have been trying to find a formula that will easily remove all the brackets and data to leave only the final percentage in the cells. I want to do this so that I can then find the average of all the scores, and currently due to the data in the square brackets, I cannot use a formula.

What I've tried:

Data > Text to Columns > Tried to cut off at the 0, but I was either doing it wrong, or it didn't work.

I also looked at extracting (removing) the first four characters, but wasn't clear how to replace that with the final percentage result in the same cell itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rethink your logic.
 A formula cannot **remove content from a cell**. For that you need a VBA macro.

However, you can write a formula that ignores cell content.

So, if `myRange` is the range over which you want to average.  Perhaps `D2:O2`?

```
=AVERAGE(--MID(myRange,FIND("]",myRange)+1,99))
```

We `FIND` the location of the closing bracket, and add 1 to that for the possible start of our desired number.

`MID` will return that number as a string, so the double unary `--` converts it to a real number.

Then `AVERAGE`.

This is an array formula and, in earlier versions of Excel, may need to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`.